# model interaction between words for a sentiment analysis task

Tags: nlp, statistics, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

I am wondering what is the most appropriate way to model the interaction between two words/variables in a language model for a sentiment analysis task. For example, in the following dataset:

```
You didn't solve my problem,NEU
I never made that purchase,NEU
You never solve my problems,NEG
```

The words "solve" and "never", in isolation, doesn't have a negative sentiment. But, when they appear together, they do. Formally speaking: assuming we have a feature «solve» that takes the value 0 when the word «solve» is absent, and 1 when the word is present, and another feature «never» with the same logic: the difference in the probability of Y=NEG between «solve»=0 and «solve»=1 is different when «never»=0 and «never»=1.

But a basic logistic regression (using, for example, `sklearn`), wouldn't be able to handle this kind of situation.
With `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` it is possible to add interaction coefficients, but it is hardly the most effective option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've solved you problem, but here is how I appraoched a similiar problem and checked the outcome of two methods:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

data = [("You didn't solve my problem", "NEU"),
        ("I never made that purchase", "NEU"),
        ("You never solve my problems", "NEG")]

X_train = [d[0] for d in data]
y_train = [d[1] for d in data]
X_test = ["I solved your problem", "You never helped me"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_train_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

X_test_features = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

nn_classifier = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), max_iter=1000, random_state=1)
nn_classifier.fit(X_train_features, y_train)

y_test_pred_nn = nn_classifier.predict(X_test_features)

print("Predicted sentiment using neural network:", y_test_pred_nn)

tree_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
tree_classifier.fit(X_train_features, y_train)

plot_tree(tree_classifier, feature_names=feature_names)

y_test_pred_tree = tree_classifier.predict(X_test_features)

print("Predicted sentiment using decision tree:", y_test_pred_tree)

y_train_pred_nn = nn_classifier.predict(X_train_features)
y_train_pred_tree = tree_classifier.predict(X_train_features)
print("Neural network performance on training data:")
print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred_nn))
print("Decision tree performance on training data:")
print(classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred_tree))
```

which returned

```
Predicted sentiment using neural network: ['NEU' 'NEU']
Predicted sentiment using decision tree: ['NEU' 'NEU']
Neural network performance on training data:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         NEG       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
         NEU       1.00      1.00      1.00         2

    accuracy                           1.00         3
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         3

Decision tree performance on training data:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         NEG       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
         NEU       1.00      1.00      1.00         2

    accuracy                           1.00         3
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         3
```

and

[image]